# Spring mvc - Server side programming

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a **spring mvc** application which i use as only a server. I have deployed some html and javascript files on my hosting account and sending post requests to my server only. Retrieve data from database and send back the data to the **html** or **javascript** pages. I don't use any **servlets**,**jsp** or **jsf**. Everywhere i look it says that i should use them however. Am i doing something wrong? It feels like bad practice but i don't know the right way to do it i guess. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think not a relevant questions u have asked.. Please clarify ur questions and explain what do u want to achieve actually

Comment: _I have a spring mvc application which i use as only a server._ i am sure you have a wrong understanding about MVC architecture.

Comment: @Vikrant Kashyap I dont want an mvc structure actually i want a plain server that gets post messages from my website and processes them then returns the value to website. I dont want to use jsp jsf or servlets in my application. Just plain server. But i think i don't know how to achieve this in Spring. I don't know what i should search for either. Can you help a little bit

Comment: You mean you don't need any View layer like jsp or html? and your server should respond back to HTTP requests with a json/xml output. which is what you are asking I guess? You can look into [Building a RESTful Web Service in Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: @Lucky Yep thats correct. I couldnt find any resource on the web though all the examples are related to mvc structure. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Just want design a rest api where a request is made and get response as a json.. Hope fully I got u :)

Comment: @Vikrant Kashyap Yep thats it. Sorry for the bad explanation. Any source you will provide will appreciated since i couldnt find much on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comments, you can look into creating a webservice. Since you are using Spring already, try this guide on [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

After creating the service, you can call it up like this, where you pass in input parameters to your rest endpoints,

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=User
```

Now your service will respond back to your `GET` request and you'll be output a JSON/xml string which you can process later at the client side. The sample json response looks like this,

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, User!"}
```

Here's another example blog article on [Spring Restful Web Service Example with JSON, Jackson and Client Program](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should first expand your question a bit since one needs to assume a lot to give you an answer.

IMO, JSF is not great and there are other better options for UI and JSPs are dead. But I'm biased since I used last time JSF 1.X and then went with Spring MVC and Angular or Spring and Apache Wicket more recently.

I used for instance Spring MVC to implement an HTTP RPC API with JSON payloads to which an Angular frontend connected and it worked just fine. I also had the feeling that everyone is doing that nowadays:).

I also guess you are using at least one servlet to configure Spring DispatcherServlet. Right?

Comment: Lets put it this way. In my controller i only want to handle post requests coming from the website. I don't want to show any view from my java code. Actually i don't need MVC structure either. I am a little bit lost sorry for the confusing explanation